# Is there a way to ignore a timer inside an rxjs pipe?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Basically title, I have a pipe that is meant to print text slowly and over time, but I want to have the option to print it out instantly, the way this pipe does it, it still has a minor delay (assuming 1 ms) .

Is it possible to make this pipe ignore the timer if its 0? I could technically make a second pipe that runs if the `this.delay` is set to 0 but I feel like there must be a way to allow this to work within the pipe

```
printString(s: string = null, person: string = "END", buttons: DialogueButtondata[] = []) {
    this.isPrinting = true;
    const obs = new Subject();

    const out = new OutputElement({ person: person });
    this.target.push(out);

    timer(0, this.delay)
      .pipe(take(s.length), finalize(() => {
        if (buttons) {
          buttons.forEach((element) => {
            this.buttons.push(element);
          });
        }
        obs.next();
      }))
      .subscribe(i => {
        out.text += s[i];
      });

    return obs;
}
```

Comment: You mean like `const x$ = this.delay === 0 of(undefined) ? : timer(0, this.delay); x$.pipe(...)`

Comment: @AluanHaddad that does not seem to execute if `this.delay` is 0. I need it to still execute, but the timer is responsible for the delayed letters appearing.

Comment: You can wrap the whole chain with a condition I guess. I'm not sure what's the problem.